# Greatest common divisor with one parameter and condition

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I have this homework question:

> Find $d = \gcd(10x+6, 3x+1) $ where $d > 5$ and $x$ is natural

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\gcd(10x+6,3x+1) = \gcd(10x+6 - 3(3x+1), 3x+1) = \gcd(x+3, 3x+1) = \gcd(3x+1 - 3(x+3), x+3) = \gcd(-8, x+3) = \gcd(8, x+3)\text{.}$$ The only way the gcd can be $>5$ is to be $8$. So for what $x$ does that happen?

Comment: @zardav Here it is simpler to use elimination - see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

$d\mid \color{#c00}{10x\!+\!6},\color{#0a0}{3x\!+\!1}\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid \overbrace{3(\color{#c00}{10x\!+\!6})-10(\color{#0a0}{3x\!+\!1})}^{\large {\rm eliminate}\ x}=8,\ $ so $\ d\mid 8,\,\ d>5\,\Rightarrow\,d = 8\ \ $ **QED**

Comment: I wasn't sure he was meant to solve for $x$ or $d$.

Comment: @Henno I don't think it says to find $\,x,\,$ but it is easy to do: $\, {\rm mod}\ 8\!:\,\ 3x\equiv -1\equiv -9\iff x\equiv -3\,\ (\Rightarrow\, 10x \equiv -6)$

Comment: He was meant to solve for $d$ :)

Comment: @zardav In any case, using the Euclidean algorithm as in Henno's answer is always a useful technique. However, as above, using equivalent modular arithmetic is often quicker and more intuitive (e.g. as above, allowing us to view the key idea as an elimination, which is not so clear using Euclid's algorithm). But one should be familiar with both techniques to be proficient at number theory.

Comment: Thanks! I prefer your answer, although both the answers are perfect :)